# laravel showing 1 after i login

Tags: laravel, authentication

When I log in Laravel, first thing that shows is `1` then it redirects me to my intended page. I have checked everywhere, there is no middleware which makes `1` to show up. I don't get what is the problem.

This is my login code:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated()
    {
       return redirect('admin/dashboard');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session::flush();
        auth::logout();
        
        return back();
    }
}
```

These are my routes

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('welcome');
// });

Auth::routes();

// Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@attemptLogin')->name('login');

Route::middleware('auth')->prefix('/admin')->name('admin.')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
```

There is not much in my routes as I just started to build my site and I am facing this error.

Comment: Is that all your code? What about your routes etc.?

Comment: @Unflux I just added the routes right now